# MS Edge: CSS3 transitions not working as expected in element inside link

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

I have a link with an element inside (let's call it Bob). Bob is the star of the link, so he wants to shine a bit differently.

The link has some CSS3 transitions to create a fade effect. Bob also has a fade effect, so he can still be the shining element of the link.

An important point is that `:hover` is related to the container (in the example, a `div`), and I need it that way.

It works great in Firefox, Chrome and IE, but Microsoft Edge doesn't like the way Bob shines. During the transition, Bob just disappears and I have no idea where he goes.

Here's an example HTML:

```
<div>
  <a href="#1">
    <span class="Bob">Bright like a diamond!</span>
    <p>Random text</p>
  </a>

  <a href="#2">Other random stuff, who cares...</a>
</div>
```

The `:hover` transition is on the `div`, then both `a` and Bob have transitions. The relevant CSS is very simple, something like:

```
div:hover .Bob { transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
.Bob { transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
div:hover a { transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
a { transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
```

Then they just have different colors so you can see the fade animations

Here's a JSFiddle so you can meet Bob: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/9vv7v6gd/

If you test it in MS Edge, you will see how Bob disappears during the transition, and we don't want that. If you change the transition times between Bob and `a`, it gets even weirder, but let's keep it simple for now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 2019. Problem has been solved by Microsoft and Edge behaves in this situation just like any other browser.

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem today. I resolved it by more specific transition property

```
{ transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
```

change to something like

```
{ transition: color 0.5s ease 0s; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this is by adding the transition result to the  element.

```
div:hover a {
    /* for example, if blue text was the desired transition. */
    color: blue;
}
```